# Error Servicio REST Glassfish y Jersey

Tags: java, glassfish

solicito de su colaboracion debido a que tengo inconvenientes al momento de constultar la peticion GET, el log del Glassfish no me arroja ningun error solamente la pagina en donde se esta deplegando, el error es:

> **The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request**

**Clase Abstracta**

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
  }

}
```

**Clase Aplicacion**

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

/**
 * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
 * It is automatically populated with
 * all resources defined in the project.
 * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
 */
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(org.api.data.service.UsuarioFacadeREST.class);
  }
}
```

**Servicio REST**

```
 @Stateless
 @Path("/usuario")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public class UsuarioFacadeREST  extends AbstractFacade<ParUsuarios>{

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ApisilaboPU") 
 private EntityManager em;

 public UsuarioFacadeREST() {
    super(ParUsuarios.class);
 }

/**
 * Metodo que crea en la db un Usuarios
 * @param entity 
 */
@POST
@Override
public void create(ParUsuarios entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

/**
 * Metodo que modifica un Usuarios en la db
 * @param id
 * @param entity 
 */
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
public void edit(@PathParam("id") int id, ParUsuarios entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

/**
 * Metodo que elimina un Usuarios de la db
 * @param id 
 */
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

/**
 * Metodo que busca un Usuarios por su id en la db
 * @param id
 * @return 
 */
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public ParUsuarios find(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

/**
 * Metodo que retorna todos los Usuarios de la db
 * @return 
 */
@GET
@Override
public List<ParUsuarios> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

  /**
   * Metodo que realizar la busqueda de varios Usuarios indicandoles un limite superior e inferior
   * @param from
   * @param to
   * @return 
   */
   @GET
   @Path("{from}/{to}")
   public List<ParUsuarios> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

/**
 * 
 * @return 
 */
@GET
@Path("count")
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
  }
}
```

**Informacion Log**

```
Información: file:/Users/mio/Desktop/poliSilabos/ApiSilabo/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_ApisilaboPU logout successful
Información: visiting unvisited references
Información: visiting unvisited references
Información: visiting unvisited references
Información: visiting unvisited references
Información: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Información: file:/Users/mio/Desktop/poliSilabos/ApiSilabo/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_ApisilaboPU login successful
Información: Portable JNDI names for EJB ParUsuarioFacadeREST: [java:global/ApiSilabo/ParUsuarioFacadeREST!org.api.data.service.ParUsuarioFacadeREST, java:global/ApiSilabo/ParUsuarioFacadeREST]
WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Información: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.api.data.service.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping /api/*, with the Application class of the same name.
Información: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
Información: Loading application [ApiSilabo] at [/ApiSilabo]
Información: ApiSilabo was successfully deployed in 560 milliseconds.
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de Glassfish que estás ocupando?

Comment: Debe haber un stacktrace. Es imposible que esta información no se muestre en GlassFish. Por favor asegúrate de revisar todos los archivos de log correspondientes.

Comment: @Rosendo Ropher glassfish 4.1

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza le realice un clean y ejecuto el servicio GET y la consola del server no presenta ningun informe

Comment: @Gdaimon quizá la consola no muestre logs porque no los tienes habilitados, pero como dice Luiggi en la carpeta de logs del propio contenedor deben haber archivos de logs con información.

Comment: @Gdaimon intenta ubicar una ruta como esta `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/<<nombre de tu domain>>/logs`, ubica en donde descomprimiste el zip yo lo tengo en `opt`

Comment: @Rosendo Ropher, ya edite el post y coloque el registro del log

Comment: @Gdaimon según el log tu aplicación se desplegó correctamente, no hay algo más? Algo que se genere cuando ejecutas el request? Un Fatal Exception dentro del log? Algo por el estilo, entiendo que ese archivo de log debe tener muuucha información.

Comment: @Rosendo Ropher, unico que hago es hacer el despliegue y posterior a ello hago el request yeso es lo que se aloja en al consola del glassfish

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39695/discussion-between-rosendo-ropher-and-gdaimon).

Comment: En primer lugar te recomendaría cambiar de servidor. Glassfish no es muy eficiente.
Si decides quedarte con él, podrías intentar volver a montar el servidor (elimínalo y configuralo de nuevo), normalmente la configuración que se tiene no es la indicada. ¡Mucha suerte! :D